# compilers and interpreters are different, but is there a difference in the role that they are executing?

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter

compilers and interpreters work differently as the compiler build the target program which will eventually will be executed, and the interpreter is the program that is running and executing command by interpreting lines of the script.
But do they have any difference in their roles? Or does they have the exact same role which is interpreting the high level source code and make it run?
Do they have other roles too?
Thank you for your help.

I searched the internet a bit but couldn't find a good source to this information.

Comment: Compilers doesn't "make it run", they "make it runnable". So yes, there's a difference. Interpreters actually execute the code, compilers translate the code from one form into another.

Comment: Thank you, note taken. So the compiler make a runnable target program, while the interpreter execute a series of commands that are created by interpreting the source code? and do they have other differences in the role that they're executing? @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Comment: This probably depends on how loose or strict you want to frame that question. A compiler generally checks all the source code to make sure it compiles whereas an interpreter might generally check it as it gets to it, it depends on the interpreter. Is this such a type of difference?

Comment: Well I wouldn't think of it as a part of their role, maybe more like a part of their "behavior". But i did find your previous answer helpful. Thank you! @LasseVågsætherKarlsen